# Gradle project sync failed while importing sample project

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:

> (17, 0) SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the
>   local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Open File
>
> proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
>   'proguard-rules.pro'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project you have a local properties file, named "local.properties".

There you need to define your path to your Android SDK. This might look like this:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

This is a sample from a Mac.